# Android Alarm setExactAndAllowWhileIdle only triggers once

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm using the `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` as follows:

```
notificationAlarmMgr?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    notificationCalendar.timeInMillis,
    notificationAlarmIntent
)
```

Before I used `setInexactRepeating` and I was able to fire the alarm once everyday:

```
notificationAlarmMgr?.setInexactRepeating(
    AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    notificationCalendar.timeInMillis,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
    notificationAlarmIntent
)
```

`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` doesn't have a `intervalMillis` parameter like `setInexactRepeating` does, so I can't pass `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` as an argument so that the alarm goes off everyday.

How do I make my alarm go off once everyday using `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`?

**Update 1:**

More code for sending the alarm:

```
notificationAlarmIntent = Intent(
    context,
    NotificationAlarmReceiver::class.java
).let { intent ->
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        NOTIFICATION_ID,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
}
```

The `BroadcastReceiver()` for the notification:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
class NotificationAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val i = Intent(context, SplashActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification))
            .setContentText(NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT_TEXT)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT_TEXT))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
            notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT_TEXT: String by lazy { "Lorem ipsum" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the other work being done by whatever `notificationAlarmIntent` invokes, have it also call `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` for the next time you want to get control.

For example, you can put your `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` code in a utility function:

```kotlin
fun setTheCottonPickinAlarm(context: Context, whenDoesItGoOff: Calendar) {
    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)

    val notificationAlarmIntent = Intent(
        context,
        NotificationAlarmReceiver::class.java
    ).let { intent ->
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    }

    alarmManager?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        whenDoesItGoOff.timeInMillis,
        notificationAlarmIntent
    )
}
```

Then, in addition to wherever you are calling the existing `AlarmManager` code, you can call it from `onReceive()` of your `NotificationAlarmReceiver`:

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
class NotificationAlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val i = Intent(context, SplashActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification))
            .setContentText(NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT_TEXT)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT_TEXT))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
            notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
        }

        setTheCottonPickinAlarm(context, calculateTheNextAlarmTime())
    }

    companion object {
        private val NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT_TEXT: String by lazy { "Lorem ipsum" }
    }
}
```

(where you would supply the `calculateTheNextAlarmTime()` implementation, or add that logic to `setTheCottonPickinAlarm()` itself)

Comment: I updated my code to include the `Intent` and `BroadcastReceiver` for the alarm. I don't quite understand how `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` can be included in the intent.

Comment: @TomDarious: Have `NotificationAlarmReceiver` call `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` for the next time you want to get control, in addition to the rest of the work that it is doing to show the `Notification`.

Comment: How is that possible? Where do I even add `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` in my `NotificationAlarmReceiver` class? The `notificationAlarmMgr?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...)` is happening in another class.

Comment: @TomDarious: "Where do I even add setExactAndAllowWhileIdle in my NotificationAlarmReceiver class?" -- as part of its `onReceive()` implementation. "The notificationAlarmMgr?.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...) is happening in another class." -- then have two copies of that code. Or put that code in a utility function that can be called from both places. Or put that code in a singleton that you inject into both places using your preferred dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).